# Set a default message for a custom error class

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have created a custom error class called `MyError` and a separate class called `MyClass` that raises this error in its class method `self.raiser`. I have also created to rspec expectations to test that MyError is raised and that MyError prints the message `my error`:

```
class MyError < StandardError
    def self.message
        'my error'
    end
end

class MyClass
    def self.raiser
        raise MyError
    end
end

describe MyClass do
    specify{ expect{ MyClass.raiser }.to raise_exception 'my error' }
    specify{ expect{ MyClass.raiser }.to raise_exception MyError }
end
```

Here's what happens when I run rspec:

```
$ rspec spec/raise_error.rb --format documentation

MyClass
  should raise Exception with "my error" (FAILED - 1)
  should raise MyError

Failures:

  1) MyClass should raise Exception with "my error"
     Failure/Error: specify{ expect{ MyClass.raiser }.to raise_exception 'my error' }
       expected Exception with "my error", got #<MyError: MyError> with backtrace:
         # ./spec/raise_error.rb:9:in `raiser'
         # ./spec/raise_error.rb:14:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
         # ./spec/raise_error.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/raise_error.rb:14:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.01662 seconds (files took 0.08321 seconds to load)
2 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/raise_error.rb:14 # MyClass should raise Exception with "my error"
```

Both of these expectations should pass. `got #<MyError: MyError>` is bizarre and makes no sense at all. It should be `got #<MyError: "my error">`

Also, I do not think this is an rspec error:

```
2.2.1 :007 >   require 'rspec'
 => true 
2.2.1 :008 > require_relative 'spec/raise_error.rb'
 => true 
2.2.1 :009 > MyClass.raiser
MyError: MyError
```

Comment: Please change `def self.message` to `def message`. And it will work

Answer (score 2):

You have to defined the method `message` as an instance method, not the class method as you tried.

I rewrote the custom error class :

```
class MyError < StandardError
  def message
    'my error'
  end
end

class MyClass
  def self.raiser
    raise MyError
  end
end
```

Here is my spec file :

```
require_relative "../a.rb"

describe MyClass do
  it 'expects the Error class message' do
    expect { MyClass.raiser }.to raise_exception 'my error'
  end

  it 'expects the Error class name' do
    expect { MyClass.raiser }.to raise_exception MyError
  end
end
```

Lets run the spec:

```
[arup@Ruby]$ rspec -fd spec/a_spec.rb

MyClass
  expects the Error class message
  expects the Error class name

Finished in 0.00232 seconds (files took 0.16898 seconds to load)
2 examples, 0 failures
```